# Bounty text doesn't look right

Tags: bug, status-completed

Take a look at [this post](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/360/google-apps-as-an-online-harddrive/1986#1986).

Notice how the bounty text ("+50" to the left of the post) doesn't look right. The font is too big and it's in gray. It should look like what the [FAQ](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/faq) shows (small white writing on red background).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have put in a fix. Should be in the next build. Thanks!

Comment: It looks like it's fixed, thanks